# Go buildmode option doesn't generate header file

Tags: python, c, go

I am writing a python program which can call a go program upon certain trigger. I am following some [links](https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/calling-go-functions-from-other-languages-4c7d8bcc69bf) and learned about buildmode which generates .so and another header (.h) file. I tried add two integer example and working perfectly. However, in my case, header file is not being generated.

The particular program I am using in go is a modified example which connects to TTN (The Things Network) and program structure looks as following:

```html
package main

import "C"

import (
//  "encoding/hex"
//  "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
//  "io/ioutil"
//  "os"

    ttnsdk "github.com/TheThingsNetwork/go-app-sdk"
    ttnlog "github.com/TheThingsNetwork/go-utils/log"
    "github.com/TheThingsNetwork/go-utils/log/apex"
    "github.com/TheThingsNetwork/go-utils/random"
    "github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/core/types"
)

const (
    sdkClientName = "my-amazing-app"
)

func main() {
    log := apex.Stdout() // We use a cli logger at Stdout
    log.MustParseLevel("debug")
    ttnlog.Set(log) // Set the logger as default for TTN

    ...
    ...

}
```

I am getting following error if trying to call from a simple python program:

```html
Loaded go generated SO library
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ttnPublishCall.py", line 5, in <module>
    result = lib.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 369, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: ./publishOnly.so: undefined symbol: main
```

I already tried to write custom header file (mentioning main function) but it doesn't work. Further, I tried to create another function which can be called from main function but no help.

Comment: *header file is not being generated* - so this is a problem with the buildmode tool? Can you show how you ran it? Try to create a [mre]. I'm not really sure what to do with the code in the question.

Comment: I just added more details, kindly have a look.

Comment: Have you [exported anything](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-C_references_to_Go) like the examples you linked to? There's no header generated if there's no symbols to reference.

Comment: Thanks @JimB , The issue is resolved with properly using //export as preamble.